# Setting multiple tags in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

When setting multiple tags for emacs headers with the "single key fast selection" all of the selected tags are marked in the list (with color) but only the last one is listed on the "Current" line and actually inserted when I exit. I.e. using single keys I can only insert one single tag, eventhough I select more.

If I hit `!` before selecting tags ("groups") then it works as I want it. How can I make this behaviour default?

My `org-fast-tag-selection-single-key` is set to `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem - the trick is to remove groups from `org-tag-alist` (delimeted by (:startgroup) (:endgroup)) - all tags between them are by default considered exclusive, therefore by default only the most recent is inserted (the highlighting seems to be a (minor) bug to me - this is confusing for the user, because the tags look selected, but are not)

Comment: If you're interested in grouping tags without making them mutually exclusive, use `:startgrouptag`, `:grouptags` and `:endgrouptag` instead of `:startgroup` and `:endgroup`